# Change autoresizingMask on programmatically created navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, orientation, uinavigationbar, autoresizingmask

So I have a view-based app in which I need one page with a tableview and I wanted a navigation bar above it to go back. I added this programmatically with:

```
-(IBAction)switchToTableView; {

    tableView *table = [[tableView alloc] initWithNibName:@"tableView" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: table];
    table.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [table release];
    [self presentModalViewController: navControl animated:YES];
    [navControl release];
}
```

Then in the viewDidLoad of the tableview class I implemented:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 70.f;

    UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                             initWithTitle:@"Back"
                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                             target:self
                             action:@selector(switchToHome)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = back;

    UIBarButtonItem *map = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Map"
                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                            target:self
                            action:@selector(switchBacktoFindArt)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = map;
    [map release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

to add the needed buttons. Now, all of this worked great, but now that I'm going through my app and allowing for orientation changes, I'm having trouble with this one since I can't change the autoresizingMask in IB. The whole tableview page resizes nicely except the navigation bar becomes very skinny top-to-bottom wise. I'd like it to stay the same height. How do I go about setting the appropriate Masks or even accessing the navigation bar outside of IB?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can play with things like this to disable height changes:

```
navControl.navigationBar.autoresizingMask ^= UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
```

But a UINavigationController might really get wonky if you play around with its internals like that. I'm surprised that the nav's bar isn't already resizing to an appropriately pleasing height, like it's supposed to do by default. (It feels like something else might be wrong elsewhere in your code, but I'd have to see more to find out).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It looked like that would work, but I placed that command in the switchToTableView method just above [table release], and unfortunately it didn't seem to do anything. Any ideas? And I think the nav's bar would be a pleasing height to most people as it is about 2/3 usual thickness, especially since a tableview in landscape makes for a small view, but I switch back and forth between a mapview and this tableview with the same nav bars so I thought it would be good to keep them uniformly thick.